# Import large pdf files to be indexed to Elastic Search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, pdf

I am trying to large pdf files to elastic search to index them.

```
uploadPDFDocument: async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            let data = req.body;
            let client = await cloudSearchController.getElasticSearchClient();
            const documentData = await fs.readFile("./large.pdf");
            const encodedData = Buffer.from(documentData).toString('base64');
            let document = {
                id: 'my_id_7',
                index: 'my-index-000001',
                pipeline: 'attachment',
                timeout: '5m',
                body: {
                    data: encodedData
                }
            }
            let response = await client.create(document);
            console.log(response);
            return res.status(200).send(response);
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.stack);
            return next(error);
        }
    },
```

The above code works for small pdf files and I am able extract data from it and index it.
But for large pdf files I get timeout exception.

Is there any other way to this without time out issue?

I have read about fscrawler, filebeats and logstash but they all deal with logs not pdf files.

Comment: FSCrawler deals with PDF files: https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/fscrawler-2.7/

Comment: We did use Apache Tika as a preprocessor for ES https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2020/03/03/searching-word-and-pdf-documents-with-elasticsearch-and-apache-tika/#:~:text=Elasticsearch%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,text%20from%20numerous%20file%20types.